# iOS In-App Purchase : Can Non-Consumable Apple Hosted Content be Free

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Can any one please confirm if "Can Non-Consumable Apple Hosted Content be Free".

I have read on lot of places including on StackOverflow that Non-Consumable cannot be free but i am looking for official apple guideline reference that states so. None of the previous answers provides any link to apple guidelines or references which clearly states this point.

if any one can please provide me with a link then that would be awesome.

Thanks
Azeem

Answer (score 5):

It was not possible before. It is possible now. <s>I think since iOS7, but if I am wrong please someone correct me.</s> It was around the time iOS7 was launched, but it is not iOS7 related anyhow. Here you can see an screenshot I just took from itunes connect, while adding a new non-consumable item. You can see that it lets me select "Free" in the tier price drop down menu [image]

Comment: It has nothing to do with iOS 7. But it is true: non-consumables may be free. Consumable items may not be set to free.

Answer (score 0):

Non consumable can be free- I think you're confusing consumable with non-consumable. Consumable would be something the user can buy more than once, like +10,000 gold in a game, non-consumable would be something the user only has to buy once, like removing ads. Non-consumable *CAN* be free.

Also, instead of posting a question and waiting for a response, you could have just went and checked yourself. Also, Apple would never let you choose for an in-app purchase to be `free` if it was agains their guidelines, just saying.

Again, *consumables* (like in-game money) **can't be free**, yet *non-consumables* (like removing ads) **can be**. They can be anything they let you choose

Comment: your contradicting yourself in your message mixing up non-consumables and consumables